# Querying the most recent posts in a MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Rather new to Mongodb/Mongoose/Node. Trying to make a query to retrieve the most recent posts (example being the 10 most recent posts) across all documents in a collection.

I tried querying this a few different ways.

```
MessageboardModel.find({"posts": {"time": {"$gte": ISODate("2014-07-02T00:00:00Z")}}} ...
```

I tried doing the above just to try getting to the proper nested time property, but everything I was trying throws an error. I'm definitely missing something here...

Here is an example document in the collection:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5c435d493dcf9281500cd177"
    },
    "movie": 433249,
    "posts": [
        {
            "replies": [],
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5c435d493dcf9281500cd142"
            },
            "username": "Username1",
            "time": {
                "$date": "2019-01-19T17:24:25.204Z"
            },
            "post": "This is a post title",
            "content": "Content here."
        },
        {
            "replies": [],
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5c435d493dcf9281500cd123"
            },
            "username": "Username2",
            "time": {
                "$date": "2019-01-12T17:24:25.204Z"
            },
            "post": "This is another post made earlier",
            "content": "Content here."
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

There are many documents in the collection. I want to get, say the most recent 10 posts, across all of the documents in the entire collection.

Any help?

Comment: You can use .dot notation. `MessageboardModel.find({"posts.time": {"$gte": ISODate("2014-07-02T00:00:00Z")}})`

Comment: You should consider moving posts into a separate collection, instead of embedding them into parent objects. If you're going to query separate posts, this change could be beneficial to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) query:

***Steps:***
1> Match Specific doc

2> Stretch docs of its array using [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/).

3> Sort using the `time` field from the `posts`.

4> Select fields , if specific fields needs to be shown.

5> Add limit, how many docs you want.

```
<YOUR_MODEL>.aggregate([
{$match:{
"movie": 433249 //you may add find conditions here, otherwise you can keep {} or remove $match from here
}},
{$unwind:"$posts"}, //this will make the each array element with different different docs.
{$sort:{"posts. time":1}}, // sort using the date field now, depends on your requirement use -1 /1
{$project:{posts:1}}, //select docs only from posts field. [u can remove if you want every element, or may modify]
{$limit:10} //you want only last 10 posts
]).exec();
```

let me know if you still having any issue or getting any error.

would love answer.